# How do I count the number of columns in a table

Tags: count, calculated-columns

How do I count the number of columns in a table in sql and display this value in web page (aspx) ?
for example , i want to get the number of ID filed in sql server to display in a web page for understand how many people are member on my web site
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean 'count the number of rows?'

If so something like `select count(id) from member_table` will give you the amount of members

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE 
TABLE_CATALOG = 'database' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'table'
```

I am not sure what database you are using but here is MS SQL's version.

Answer (score 0):

MSSQL Count Columns:

> SELECT COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_CATALOG = 'database' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = 'table'

But I suspect you mean Rows?

Comment: @Eugene Roeder - Beat me to it... ;)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT COUNT(column_name) FROM table_name

e.g.:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users
```

will return you a number of registered users